# New_post in blogdown doesn't make Rmarkdown files

Tags: r, r-markdown, blogdown

I'm trying to practice the blogdown with one of hugo themes but I cannot make new Rmarkdown posts using: Addins > New Post > <>.

When I click done, there is no file in the editor or in the filesystem, and the Console reports:

```
blogdown:::new_post_addin()

Listening on http://127.0.0.1:4288
C:\Users\82105\Desktop\blogdown2\content\en\post\2020-07-16-afsf.en.md created
Warning in file(con, "r") :
  cannot open file 'content/post/2020-07-16-afsf.en.md': No such file or directory
Warning: Error in file: cannot open the connection
  91: file
  90: readLines
  87: hugo_toYAML
  86: new_content
  85: blogdown::new_post
  84: observeEventHandler
  13: shiny::runApp
  12: shiny::runGadget
  11: eval
  10: eval
   4: eval
   3: eval
   2: sys.source
   1: blogdown:::new_post_addin
```

My hugo version is 0.73.0.
The link of theme I'm using is [hugo-theme-zdoc theme](https://github.com/zzossig/hugo-theme-zdoc)

Thank you.

Comment: maybe your current directory is not the primary directory. Make sure your `getwd()` shows `C:\Users\82105\Desktop\blogdown2` before running `blogdown::new_post()`, also you will have to give a title like `blogdown::new_post("intro to blog")`. In my exeperience, starting over with a brand new project to start fresh helped remove various errors.

Comment: Would you please provide a reproducible example?